# How to create a progress bar of no. of Videos watched

Tags: javascript

I want to create a progress bar for no. of video watched. I do have 5 videos - video1.mp4, video2.mp4, video3.mp4, video4.mp4, video5.mp4. actually it will be a course progress bar.  The link of the 5 videos are like - mywebsite.com/video1.mp4.   Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it using jQuery. Basically create a sprite that is adjusted when the `videos_watched` variable is incremented.

**css**

```
.video_link {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#progress_sprite { /* use a sprite with different progress levels. */}
```

**html**

```
<p class="video_link" id="video_01">
  Watch Video 1
</p>
<p class="video_link" id="video_02">
  Watch Video 2
</p>
<p class="video_link" id="video_03">
  Watch Video 3
</p>
<p class="video_link" id="video_04">
  Watch Video 4
</p>
<div id="progress_sprite"></div>
<p id="videos_watched">
  Videos Watched: <span>0</span>
</p>
```

**js**

```
  var videos_watched = 0;

  $(".video_link").on("click", function() {
    if (!($(this).hasClass("viewed"))) {
      $(this).addClass("viewed");
      videos_watched = videos_watched + 1;
      update_sprite();
      //This was added to show progress on fiddle. Not really 
      //needed for progress bar.
      $("#videos_watched span").html(videos_watched);
    }
  });

  function update_sprite() {
    switch (videos_watched) {
      case 0:
        $("#progress_sprite").css('backgroundPosition', '50% 0px');
        break;
      case 1:
        $("#progress_sprite").css('backgroundPosition', '50% -57px');
        break;
      case 2:
        $("#progress_sprite").css('backgroundPosition', '50% -114px');
        break;
      case 3:
        $("#progress_sprite").css('backgroundPosition', '50% -171px');
        break;
      case 4:
        $("#progress_sprite").css('backgroundPosition', '50% -228px');
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
```

**Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/6jr3qjaa/1/

Comment: It's better than paying taxes.

Comment: But when i refresh the page, it again goes back to zero....    I am creating an online course....  And im trying to create a progress metre/bar which tells them there course progress